# Возможно ли получать через VK API упоминания в постах?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли получать упоминания в постах? Допустим, пользователь N хочет получить скидку на продукт X. Условие скидки - сделать репост из группы Y. После этого бот выдаст пользователю N промокод, после проверки его стены.

Я никогда не работал с VK API, поэтому не понимаю, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы мой бот в ТГ отправлял запрос в вк, и получал ответ, есть ли этот репост, или нет

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое вполне можно создать. Расскажу в общих чертах, как это должно работать:

1. Пользователю делает репост записи.
2. Пользователь отправляет сообщение / нажимает на кнопку / как либо говорит боту, что он выполнил условия.
3. Бот, при помощи метода [`wall.get`](https://dev.vk.com/method/wall.get) получает первые N [записей на стене](https://dev.vk.com/reference/objects/post) пользователя и проверяет наличие репоста (поле [`reply_owner_id`](https://dev.vk.com/reference/objects/post#reply_owner_id) и [`reply_post_id`](https://dev.vk.com/reference/objects/post#reply_post_id)).
4. Бот отправляет в сообщения промокод.

Конкретная реализация будет зависеть от выбора библиотеки, поэтому код не привожу.

---

Также есть событие [`wall_repost`](https://dev.vk.com/api/community-events/json-schema#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5), через него можно моментально узнавать о новых репостах. Тогда можно миновать пункты 2 и 3.